# How to stop/restrict execution of some method (~when already some object is calling that)

Tags: java, implementation, rmi, distributed-computing

i am stuck in a situation, where i need to move balls in multi-user way, i m using RMI
in a distributed animation of moving BALLS .

My goal is to move multiple balls in a way, so that multiple clients observe the same movement/position of balls, i m using ball object which is remote object.

**My problem is:** *i am calling the move function,  which is remote and increasing no of clients causes calling that function more frequently and it causes ball speed more and more because of increasing no of calls to this method from different clients.*

can somebody please recommend me that how  could i cope with this problem that when  ball is already moving on one client then other ball don't call the function but just utilize that.

here is code :

```
public void start() {
        Play = true;
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

public void run() {

    while (Play == true) {
        runball();
        pit.repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            stop();
        }
    }
}

public void runball() {

    try {
            aBall.setBounds(pit.getWidth(), pit.getHeight());
            aBall.move();
            }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

and there is my remote move method:

```
public  void move() throws RemoteException {
        // ... Move the ball at the give velocity.
        m_x += m_velocityX;
        m_y += m_velocityY;

    if (m_x < 0) { // If at or beyond left side
        m_x = 0; // Place against edge and
        m_velocityX = -m_velocityX;

    } else if (m_x > m_rightBound) { // If at or beyond right side
        m_x = m_rightBound; // Place against right edge.
        m_velocityX = -m_velocityX;
    }

    if (m_y < 0) { // if we're at top
        m_y = 1;
        m_velocityY = -m_velocityY;

    } else if (m_y > m_bottomBound) { // if we're at bottom
        m_y = m_bottomBound;
        m_velocityY = -m_velocityY;

    }

}
```

Can somebody please guide me , there is some problem in this design and i m using the RMI in wrong way? or recommend me some design by which i can accomplish my goal.

thanks a lot,

jibby

Comment: Are you saying that if the ball is already moving then additional requests should be ignored until the ball stops moving?

Comment: "Are you saying that if the ball is already moving then additional requests should be ignored" Yes, "until the ball stops moving" that is not the concern yet.

Comment: @static void main - it may be a concern - read Stephen C's posting below.  If the client is moving the ball to its destination in steps, then the server has no mechanism to know when the client has completed the entire move and is done.  If it must be done this way you will need to add "lock" and "unlock" functions to the server.  The client would then be able to own the server until the move was completed. Be aware that if a client doesn't issue an unlock() however you can have problems.

Comment: Does each client move its own ball or do they all share one ball?  And sorry to be dense, but are the start(), run(), and runBall() methods part of the client or part of the server?

Comment: i thought you are talking about implementing synchronization that is not the issue here.i just wanted to stop execution of move because of more no of calls increasing speed.like 1 sec = 1 call, for two clients 1 sec= 2 calls, it is causing increase in speed so i want to ignore second call.

Comment: How is the velocity of the ball set?  move() accepts no arguments.

Comment: i have getter and setters for that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your clients should be telling the server to move the ball(s).

Instead, there should be a server thread that moves the ball at the required rates.  The clients should simply be asking the server where the ball currently is.

Comment: By the time the client code gets the result, the information might well be out of date.  I don't think telling the server where to put the ball is a bad idea.  What if he were aiming a telescope instead?

Comment: Unless the client is moving the ball to its final destination in chunks instead of just naming the destination and letting the server code move it there.  It's hard to tell in the code above why the loop is there.

Comment: The problem is that he has N client all telling the server to move the ball.  If you look at what "move()" does, you'll see why that is a problem.

Comment: @Static Void Main - I realized that.  I simply don't understand why you've designed the system so that the clients are controlling the "physics".

Comment: The loop is nothing else but a general "game loop" updating the objects in this case (move ball one step) and rendering the new graphics.

Comment: @Stephen C:i didn't see any other design/example implementation i know the concept of polling and pushing  and one of them  have better application here but i was unable to find the concrete /compact implementation, now i worked a lot on this and i want it to work.

Comment: see my question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846422/optimized-design-for-multiuser-simulation-with-rmi-polling-pushing

Comment: Well, that's quite another thing entirely.